# Redirect, php contact form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Hi Guys so I'm building a contact from. At the moment a message is displayed once the user submits, however I wish the php script to automatically divert to the websites homepage once submitted...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@here.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "New Message - Social Contact Form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['country']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $country = $_POST['country']; // not required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
header('Location: http://www.websitehere.com'); 
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

What do I need to add / change?

Comment: Well you're sending `$_POST['countries']` and validate on `$_POST['country']`. And `type="country"` is superfluous.

Comment: ... how did i miss that! Copied the select tab from the web and didnt see that!

Comment: Look up `header('Location: index.php');` in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending email do add below line by changing url to your home page.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/home');
```

Some time it return error in redirect so you can use javascript in php as like below

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/home';</script>";
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: is there any error? have you tried second solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed text input to drop down.

Still, you need not change its name.

Also, keep option text and value same.

This will ensure that you are getting correct data from user.

**Change**

```
 <select id="countries" name="countries" type="country" class="form-control">
<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
```

**To:**

```
 <select id="countries" name="country" type="country" class="form-control">
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
```

Comment: Thank you all changed I have updated the question as while doing this I came acorss another thing Id like to change, would you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Just use php header function to redirect after sending mail..

```
...
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header('Location: wherever.php');
...
```

If you want to show some message to user and then redirect.... use below function....

```
....
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" ); 
echo 'contact form has been submitted successfully. You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. '; 
....
```